# How to generate report in this module odoo i have done this much?

Tags: python, xml, odoo

Everythin is working fine but i am not able to get report when i click on print button

In feedback module i have following way of files **, feedback_report.xml,hourly_feedback.py,hourly_feedback.xml,__init__.py ,__openerp__.py.Have views folder inside this ,report_hourly.xml**

feedback_report.xml has following code .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <report
            id="action_hourly_feedback"
            string="Hourly Report"
            model="hourly.form"
            report_type="qweb-pdf"
            name="hourly.form.report_hourly"
            file="hourly.form.report_hourly"
        />
    </data>
</openerp>
```

hourly_feedback.py has following code

```
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
from openerp import api
import logging

class hourly_form(osv.Model):
    _name = 'hourly.form'
    _rec_name = 'assetmodelid_add'
    _columns = {

        'assetmodelid_add' : fields.many2one('agile.portfolio1','Asset Model Code',),
        'folio_num1' : fields.many2one('asset.asset','Folio Num',),
        'inspection_name' : fields.many2one('asset1.inspection','Inspection Type'),

    }
hourly_form()
```

hourly_feedback.xml has following code ,

```
<record model='ir.ui.view' id="hour_event">
    <field name="names">hourly.form.form</field>
    <field name="model">hourly.form</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Hours">
            <group>

                <field name="assetmodelid_add" />
                <field name="folio_num1" domain="[('assetmodelid_add', '=', assetmodelid_add)]"/>
                <field name="inspection_name" domain="[('assetmodelid_add', '=', assetmodelid_add)]"/>

            </group>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>

<record id="hourly_event_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Hourly Form</field>
    <field name="res_model">hourly.form</field>
    <field name="view_type">form</field>
    <field name="help" type="html">
    <p class="oe_view_nocontent_creat"> Click here</p>
    </field>
</record>

<menuitem id="hourlyfeed_form_creation" name="Hourly Maintainace Form" parent="base.menu_mro_root" />
<menuitem id="hfeed_form_creation" name="Hourly Maintainace Form" parent="hourlyfeed_form_creation" action="hourly_event_action"/>

</data>
</openerp>
```

**openerp**.py has following code

```
{
    'name':'Hourly Form',
    'version':'1.0',
    'description':"""
        Feedback Form
    """,
    'author':'shrihar',
    'depends':['base_setup','calendar','Configuration','asset','stock','asset_edit','calander_extended',],
    'data':['hourly_feedback.xml','views/report_hourly.xml','feedback_report.xml',],
    'demo':[],
    'installable':True,
    'auto_install':False,
}
```

In view/report_feedback.xml has following code

```
<openerp>
<data>
<template id="report_hourly">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
            <t t-call="report.external_layout">
                <div class="page">
                    <h2>Hour Report</h2>

                </div>
            </t>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
</data>
</openerp>
```

everything is working fine but i am not able to get report its gettin json error pleas add code

Comment: What is all this supposed to do? What error _exactly_ are you getting? Please copy & paste the error message into your post

Comment: just i wanted to get report of this i mean pdf file with those field names

Comment: okay, got it, but you really should add the error message to your question as in its current state it's difficult to come up with any ideas.

Comment: its getting Exception during JSON request handling.

Comment: I understand, but _which one exactly_? It should be printed to your console

Comment: i have done same thing for other module it is working fine just i want get one pdf file in after clicking print button

Comment: see its fine with field after clicking print module i want get one pdf file atleast i have tried with it but it was shoing same error

Comment: configuration of **qweb-pdf**

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

http://192.168.11.85:8078/web/js/web.assets_backend/dcf0aa6:2965

Comment: that's the error message that can be useful. I suggest you to add it to your question so no one has to read lots of comments to get it. What you can do is to check the encoding of the contents of this URL. There might be some non-printable characters that are not-ASCII or something like this.

Comment: i want one demo code or module which is able to get pdf files using qweb-pdf  any demo module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`report_hourly` template is defined under `views/report_feedback.xml`, so you need to add `views/report_feedback.xml` to data in `__openerp__.py`.

Comment: can u send me tha module with zipped shridharivani@gmail.com it will be very helpful